# How many times would this algorithm run?

Tags: python

I have a function in python to calculate the prime factors of a number:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
```

My question is, how many times will the program run to stop on input n?
I can figure it out fairly easy if you take an example such as 56, but abstractly, I cannot seem to write a "formula" for how many times the program will run before having calculated all prime factors.

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: What makes you think there's a formula?

Comment: @PeterWood I think ASm is looking for a running time analysis of some sort, q.v. this [Programmers Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/197374/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-algorithm-to-check-if-a-number-is-prime) article for a similar problem.

Comment: FWIW, this is an implementation of [Trial Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division)

Comment: @barakmanos In-place floor division in Python 3

Comment: @zehnpaard: What do you need floor division if both `n` and `i` are integers?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Big O notation is different to a having a formula for how many times something will loop.

Comment: @barakmanos In Python3 -- `100/3 = 33.333...` while `100//3 = 33`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time explaining what I'm after. So if my input is 56, the program returns 4 prime factors. So for an arbitrary number of inputs how many prime factors would I get?

Comment: You want to be able to tell how many prime factors a number N has, before calculating what they are?

Comment: @ASm if that's *really* your question, there's no "rule" that doesn't involve (basically) factoring *n* -- [the numbers are all over the place](http://oeis.org/A001222/graph) -- its often called the big Omega function -- [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor#Omega_functions) or [this may be of some interest](http://oeis.org/A001222)

Comment: Formulating this exactly is possible but tedious - the sum of the exponents of each prime factor, plus the count of each non-prime between 2 and the maximum evaluated i (which can be the largest prime factor, the second largest prime factor, or the square root of the largest prime factor based on certain conditions).  But maybe you want algorithmic complexity, in which case the problem is much easier...

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of the square root of the largest prime factor, but I was unsure if that was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a mathematics question than a programming question, but kinda interesting...

Let the prime factorization of `n` be of the form:

[image: equation]

Where `P1` is the smallest prime factor, `P2` is the 2nd smallest etc, and `Pk` is the largest prime factor.

There are two groups of loop iterations to think about:

1. number of loops that occur because `i` is a prime factor of `n`
2. number of loops that occur because `i` is not a prime factor of `n`

### Group 1

This number is easier, because it's always the same formula.  It's the sum of each of the exponents of the prime factors minus 1, i.e.:

[image: equation]

If you think about how the code acts when `i` is a prime factor (i.e. keeps looping while dividing `n` by `i`), the sum of the exponents should be fairly intuitive.  You subtract 1 because the last append occurs outside the loop.

### Group 2

The second group of loops is slightly more tricky, because the formula itself is actually dependent on whether `az > 1`, and also on the relative size of `Pk` and `P(k-1)` (the second smallest prime factor of `n`).

If `ak > 1`, then the last `i` that went through the loop had the value `Pk`.  So the non-prime factor values of `i` that were evaluated are all the numbers between 2 and `Pk` that are not in the set `P1` through to `Pk`.  The formula for this turns out to be:

[image: equation]

Remember `k` is the number of distinct prime factors of `n`.  You subtract 1 at the end because it's between 2 and `Pk`, not 1 and `Pk`.

On the other hand, let's think about the case where `ak = 1` (and `ak < 1` is impossible, because `ak` is the exponent on the largest prime factor - it's got to be 1 or bigger).  Then `i` never took the value of `Pk`, as the loop ends before that point because of the `while i * i <= n:` condition.

So in that case, what's the maximum value that `i` will take?  Well it depends.

Remember that if `ak = 1`, then the last value that `n` took was `Pk`.  If the second largest prime factor `P(k-1)` is bigger than the square root of `Pk`, then once the loop finishes with `i = P(k-1)`, it will immediately exit the loop - so the largest `i` is `P(k-1)`.  On the other hand, if the square root of `Pk` is bigger, then the loop will continue up to that level before exiting.  So the biggest `i` when `ak = 1` is equal to `max(P(k-1), Pk**0.5)`.  The formula for the number of loops here would look like:

[image: equation]

which simplifies to:

[image: equation]

Notice that we take the floor of the square root of Pk, because `i` will only take integer values.

### One formula to...

You put it all together, and it yields:

[image: equation]

Comment: The equations all look the same

Comment: Great answer!  @ASm You should take a look at this!

Comment: sorry, just found that sciweaver is a bit flaky when it comes to consistently showing formulae on SO - replaced with mathurl.com images which appear to be much more stable

Comment: This is what I was looking for. My maths skills aren't strong enough to have figured this out for myself, but very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

- The loop executes about `max(prime_factors(n))` times?
- If `n` is prime, then the worst case is `n` times.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and since you are not using recursive calls; you are asking "how many times the while loop will execute in order to generate all prime numbers given integer `n`".

In your code; you are running a `while loop` with the condition `i * i <= n`. But since you are manipulating the variable `i` inside your method the answer is complex(refer @dnozay's answer).

If you are interested read [this](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html) link which tells how complex it is. Keep read on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) link to get insight on prime-counting function.